# How can I prove this series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$
\frac{x}{\sqrt{(x+1)}} = \frac{x}{x+1}+ \frac{x^2}{2(x+1))^{2}}  + \frac{3x^3}{4(x+1))^{3}} +\dots
$$

I tried using Maclaurin's series.But obviously I don't get this form as the series is not just in terms of powers of $x$ but $\dfrac{x}{x+1}$.

I also tried to find the $S_{inf}$ (sum) for the right hand series but I couldn't get a closed form.
It's not a homework problem.I just saw this problem in a book and I thought I could solve this but I couldn't.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, please write the general term of the RHS series.

Comment: can you give us the reference of this series?

Comment: It's from a book and the book is not in English and I want to point something the series is x/(x+1) + 1/2 (x/(x+1))^2 + 3/4(x/(x+1))^3 .. Someone edited it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing 
$$t:=\frac{x}{x+1} $$ makes the function at interest

$$\sqrt{x} \sqrt{t}=\sqrt{\frac{t}{1-t}}\sqrt{t}=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t}}. $$

Now the problem is reduced to expressing the above in powers of $t$, which is done through the Maclaurin series around $t=0$.